# access date format in query not working

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table in date format dd/mm/yyyy in access 2007. Even in regional setting it is UK format - dd/mm/yyyy

But when I write a query to filter records for dates from the table.

I have to write like this #07/01/2012#.

```
select * from table1
where datecolumn between #07/01/2012# and #07/03/2012#
```

If I write #01/07/2012# it shows no data.

```
select * from table1
where datecolumn between #01/07/2012# and #03/07/2012#
```

But from 13/07/2012, if I write using the format #13/07/2012#, it works fine.

```
select * from table1
where datecolumn between #13/07/2012# and #14/07/2012#
```

I have an issue till 1st July to 12th July. I'm not sure where is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dates need to be unambiguous, so year, month, day is usually safest.

```
select * from table1
where datecolumn between #2012/07/01# and #2012/07/03#
```

Once the day goes over 12, the date becomes less ambiguous, or unambiguous, if the year is 4 digit, because there is no month 13.

Comment: thanks...Can you let me know how I can correct it? In table, the dates are shown in dd/mm/yyyy and I want to access them using the same format while using query. Is it possible

Comment: Where are you running the query? Query window, VBA? Where are the dates coming from? A form, an input? It is not broken, so you can't fix it :)

Comment: actually im trying to access it from html form and asp. It shows no result if date is selected till 12th July from calendar in form. but if I select 7th april 2012  from calendar, it shows result for 4th july 2012 . Then i checked in access, same thing happens in access also...I have to write 07/01/2012 to 07/12/2012 instead of 01/07/2012 to 12/07/2012 as I wrote in original question

Comment: With asp classic I reckon you are stuck with changing to year, month, day format. You can use DatePart : http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datepart.asp